# WSO2 Cluster ELB

Tags: wso2, load-balancing

i was following the wso2 clustering reference documentation.
In the section dealing with load balancer configuration I read read an example speaking about the configuration of 2 elbs. Being more precise it is described the configuration of each node specifing the "sibling" member tag in the axis2.xml file. Elb1 points elb2 and viceversa.
The question is: what the way i can specify unique public cluster host name wich external client have to point to?

Should i have to put another load balancer in front of the 2 clustered elbs the way it self becomes the single access point of the below cluster? Or this is not necessary?

Comment: Tag [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka clustering) is a data mining technique, please pay more attention when tagging. Also, this question is about server administration. Voting to  **migrate to ServerFault**

Comment: Sorry but i ve already changed the tag into just clustering As i realize the mistake yesterday... maybe the change was not committed because of a connection leak... however i think that clustering is a right tag as my question refers to wso2 clustring configuration

Comment: [tag:clustering] is an alias for cluster analysis (make sure to read the tag description). For servers it is too vague to be useful. There is load-balancing, there is hot standby, there is hadoop, beowulf etc. - quite different things that have as little in common as "networking".

Comment: Ok i see... but i m with my.phone and i cannot see any tag description. I thought clustering and clustering analysis were considered 2 distinct concepts

Comment: There is more than one "clustering". The tag is synonymous to "cluster analysis". Yeah, the phone app is buggy, and should display the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try two ELBs to get High-Availability, Fail-Proof ELB Deployment.  In this case, according to documentation you should have Keepalived (http://www.keepalived.org) installed on both host to check their availability and front them with a virtual IP address.

So, short answers are: 1) Virtual IP, 2) Not necessarily.

Have a look to this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ELB203/Automatic+Failover) where you can find more information on how to implement the scenario described above.